# Number of independent real parameters in a rank deficient Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is possibly a very trivial question, but I'm having some trouble to figure out the answer by myself (I have an intuitive guess but I cannot prove it).

What is the number of independent **real** parameters in a complex-valued Hermitian $d \times d$ matrix with rank $r<d$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $2 r d - r^2 $, for a basic proof see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110189/number-of-parameters-needed-to-specify-a-hermitian-matrix-of-rank-r) on mathoverflow.